# Entity Framework Adding Existing Item Causes Clone

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I'm using the Entity Framework v4 for a small project. Normally I use NHibernate. My issue is that I accidentally had code which added an object which was already persisted to the DB Context's collection, and when I did a SaveChanges(), the EF made a copy of the object, giving it a new Primary Key.

While this is useful, it's not what I wanted. Is there a way to turn off that functionality, and instead have an exception thrown?

UPDATE: CODE NOW INCLUDED

```
public class CcUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string TrackingId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string MembershipGuid { get; set; }

    public bool CookiesConfirmed { get; set; }
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }

}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CcUser> Users { get; set; }

}

MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();

var ccUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.TrackingId == id);   
ccUser.Modified = DateTime.UtcNow;
db.Users.Add(ccUser);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Can you show the code wich caused the issue?

Answer (score 1):

How do you know that it was the same object?

For example if it was because it had the same name, then you could add a unique index on the name field. That way adding a duplicate row would throw an exception.

Comment: It had the same primary key. I retrieved it with a FirstOrDefault, modified one non-key property, and added to the list, and saved. The result was another object, rather than an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it without the line to add the ccuser  (eg the penultimate line). If the object is already attached to the context, savechanges() should persist the changes. If that doesn't work then try calling detectchanges() before savechanges().

Comment: I know that, but if I accidentally add an existing object I want EF to throw a PK collision exception not overwrite my PK and clone!

Comment: is your primary key an identity column? if so then i think ef code-first will mark it as store generated and any attempt to add an entity will ignore any previously set value. i think you'll either have to first check if an entity exists with that primary key and update the relevant entity or try to attach a detached entity to the context. add does what it's name suggests

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who run into that problem:

Method `.Add` marking `entity` with `EntityState.Added`. And when you add existent in context item EF would consider it as a new object because of the Lazy Loading.

And afterwards `context.SaveChanges()` will generate new primary key for added item and save it to `DB`.

Use `AddOrUpdate` if you dont need that feature.

Here related question on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/91adbc66-035d-4902-af6f-b1add5255311/creating-a-copy-of-an-entity-object?forum=adodotnetentityframework)